# Retrofit 2 - get error-object JSON (few POJO for same request)

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I have simple request like

```
  /*LOGIN*/
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("v1/user/login") //your login function in your api
        Call<LoginResponce> login(@Field("identity") String identity,
               @Field("password") String password);
```

Which returns either LoginResponceobject if http code 200

```
{"token":"itwbwKay7iUIOgT-GqnYeS_IXdjJi","user_id":17}
```

Or Error Json, describes exact error, if something went wrong

```
{"status":4,"description":"user provided token expired"}
```

How can I handle error status in response?

I tried this, but it doesn't see JSON in raw text (doens't work). And doesn't seems to be nice solution.

```
mCallLoginResponse.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponce>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<LoginResponce> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    if (response.isSuccess()) {

                        registerWithToken(response.body().getToken());
                    } else { //some error in responce

                        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                        ApiError mApiError = gson.fromJson(response.raw().body().toString(), 
ApiError.class); //Exception here - no JSON in String
                            //todo error handling
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get access to the response body when you have an error code, use [`errorBody()`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/Response.html#errorBody--) instead of `body()`.  Also, there is a `string` method on `ResponseBody` that you should use instead of `toString`.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
try {
    ApiError mApiError = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(),ApiError.class); 
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle failure to read error
}
```

Comment: This throws IOException. Why?
response.errorBody().toString() doesn't work. I expect it returns raw string of responce.

Comment: Yes, `string` can throw an `IOException` because the body is streaming.  When you call `string`, the response is read off the network.

Comment: Does it mean retrofit doesn't read body in case of non 200 code?
How can I read response off the network in the body of asynchronius network call? As of my understanding "onResponse" callback executed after network connection is done.
So, if retrofit will send new requests, this mean I cannot put "onResponse" in UI thread, which I do now.

Comment: That is a valid concern.  Digging into it deeper, you do not need to worry about network on the main thread here -- retrofit reads the network response into a buffer and streams it to you from the buffer.